# Twilio outgoing Dailpad implementation

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

In my case on an outgoing call, we create conference room first and add the participant. that working now. but if the call initiator press 3 (any number) we need to gather to go to specific IVR menu.

How can I do that.. ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

There is a challenge of collecting DTMF on an active conference call. Does the initiator have access to a GUI and can thus press a button on the application to initiate this logic (say by updating the necessary conference participant call sids?

If they are on a phone only and must use a TUI interface, the only option is to investigate the hang up on star dial attribute to modify the conference in some way and redirect accordingly.